# Java to Kotlin generics translation

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

I want move to Kotlin old Java project, and found interesting, can't translate this to Kotlin without pain

```
public interface BaseJView<P extends BaseJPresenter> {
    P createPresenter();
}
public interface BaseJPresenter<V extends BaseJView> {
    void bindView(V view);
}
```

Can you give advice, how I can achive this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to employ [recursive type definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type) like so:

```
interface BaseJView<TSelf : BaseJView<TSelf, P>, P : BaseJPresenter<P, TSelf>> {
    fun createPresenter(): P
}

interface BaseJPresenter<TSelf : BaseJPresenter<TSelf, V>, V : BaseJView<V, TSelf>> {
    fun bindView(view: V)
}
```

You can then have:

```
class Presenter : BaseJPresenter<Presenter, View> {
    override fun bindView(view: View) { ... }
}
class View : BaseJView<View, Presenter> {
    override fun createPresenter(): Presenter { ... }
}
```